# Creating and Deserialize graph.microsoft.com objects

Tags: azure, microsoft-graph-api

We are using graph.microsoft.com to integrate our .NET application with Office365. For each object like event and we are now creating our own classes. Can we automatically create the classes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create your own classes for all of the type of graph.microsoft.com but this means you have to keep track of changes yourself and for the complex types this is quite some work. Better to use the Microsoft.Graph SDK for .NET:

https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Graph

For .NET the SDK is at 1.0. For other platform you can find status at: https://graph.microsoft.io/en-us/code-samples-and-sdks